# Detecting if a page crashes within an Android WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView within my android application that displays a webapp which occasionally will crash if something goes wrong (Like an "Aw snap" Google Chrome crash). I want to detect if this page has crashed, and reload it if it has.

Is there any way to detect if the page within an Android WebView crashes and then reload said page?

Comment: WebViewClient has onReceivedError(), but I'm not sure that works for "Aw, snap!" crashes. Isn't it better to address what's causing that on the webpage side?

Comment: @KT_ Unfortunately the webapp is not something that I really have control over, so I can't address those issues on the webapp side.

Comment: @KT_ on large apps, thish can happen if you exceed the amount of available RAM, which is more limited on tablets.
having this would allow reloading the page if a crash has been detected.